# Haamek Davar's implication that God used childbearing terminology

Tags: pregnancy-birth, parashat-lech-lecha, abraham, sarah, haamek-davar

The *Haamek Davar* explains Genesis 17:16–19 as follows: In verse 16, God tells Abraham that He "will give [Abraham] a son from" Sarah. Because Sarah is no longer physically capable of childbearing, Abraham understands this blessing as meaning that there will be a boy whom Sarah adopts and then presents to Abraham as his. In verse 17, Abraham expresses this understanding, and in verse 18 he prays that the adopted child be Ishmael. In verse 19, God clarifies that "your wife Sarah will give birth to a son for you" and not just rear one. [Note that God never uses the word "born" or "birth" or the like until verse 19.]

However, the wording of the *Haamek Davar* is puzzling to me. In [his commentary on verse 17](http://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Davar_on_Genesis.17.17), he writes that the adopted child

> will thereby be called "born to her", like "a son was born to Naomi" [Ruth 4:17]….

Why does *Haamek Davar* feel a need to explain how the son would be considered born to Sarah, as if this clarifies God's earlier statement that that would take place? God had never said a son would be born to Sarah, that we need to explain such wording as meaning adoption. I mean, the *Haamek Davar*'s wording I just quoted sounds like an allegorical reading of a verse, except that there's no verse he could be explaining this way.

And then in verse 19 he does it again: When God clarifies that Sarah will give birth, *Haamek Davar* explains that it's

> not like you're thinking — rather, she'll give birth, in its usual meaning.

"In its usual meaning" sounds, again, like he's referring to some statement of God's, "give birth", that Abraham had misinterpreted as adoption and that God was now clarifying really does mean giving birth. But there's no such statement! What gives?

Answer (score -1):

According to *Ha'amek Davar*'s reading, Abraham understands the blessing to predict that Sarah may adopt a boy who will be considered her own.

Abraham asks:

> הַלְּבֶן מֵאָה שָׁנָה **יִוָּלֵד** וְאִם שָׂרָה הֲבַת תִּשְׁעִים שָׁנָה **תֵּלֵד**?‏

Notice that here Abraham asks if Sarah will **give birth** (תלד), even though Hashem didn't use the word "birth" (as you mentioned).

But if Abraham is asking about Sarah **giving birth**, how does *Ha'amek Davar* explain that Abraham was thinking of **adoption**? So he explains that even an adopted child may be considerd "born" to someone other than his parents, just like it says "יֻלַּד-בֵּן לְנָעֳמִי" ("a son was born to Naomi" - even though he was Ruth's).

Comment: I think Abraham said (_b'libo_, to himself) "She can't give birth! [God must therefore mean adoption.]" and (to God) "_lu…_". I tried (obviously insufficiently) to make that clear in my description of verse 17 in the question.

Comment: @msh210 I think this reading ignores the whole part where the *Ha'amek Davar* feels the need to explain how could it be that such an adopted son is called "born". He is explaining - "yes, I know that Abraham used the verb "born", but you can think of an adopted child as 'born', so there's no contradiction.". Otherwise, that whole explanation is redundant.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, that redundancy is basically my question, above. I don't think that this answer is correct though, because I don't see how Abraham's mentioning birth would be relevant here.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, it is exactly your question, and I don't see any other way of answering it. You're assuming Abraham asks "how could she give birth? Hashem probably means adoption", but if this is the case - there's no need in explaining why the word "birth" can be considered adoption (quite the contrary). However, if Abraham is asking "will I and Sarah receive a child and adopt him?", then we need that explanation - how can we say that he's asking about adoption, if he uses the word "birth"? Here comes the explanation - an adopted child can be considered "born".

Comment: "נסתפק בכונת הדבור וגם נתתי ממנה ולא אמר וגם תלד. ע״כ אולי אין הכונה שתלד ממש אלא אופן אחר שיהי נדבק בה איזה ילד. אשר יהא כרוך אחריה ויהי נקרא בזה יולד לה": This means Abraham caught on to the fact that God didn't say "תלד" and inferred that Sarah won't "תלד" (end of :17). Your splitting (in the answer) "תלד" from "יולד" I think can't be sustained. That said, I suppose you could argue nonetheless that he's saying "she'll תלד = adopt". But the questioning ה argues against that.

Comment: @msh210 I didn't split them, they're both meant as your second option in your last comment: "Will a 100-year-old adopt a new child (יולד)? Will a 90-year-old woman adopt a new child (תלד)?" Only this way, we need the Natziv's explanation that "תלד" and "adoption" can be one and the same. Otherwise, Abraham is displaying disbelief at the idea of giving birth to a child at such an age, something the Natziv says is not possible.

Comment: He never said A. can't disbelieve in childbirth: only that A. can't disbelieve God. (A. therefore understands God as meaning adoption.) According to your read, A. disbelieves adoption after God promised adoption. That's ruled out by "חלילה לא נסתפק א״א ביכולת הקב״ה".

Comment: @msh210 Abraham is amazed at ״תלד״/״יולד״, that's obvious. This either means that he is amazed at a child being **born**, or at a child being **adopted**. Only the latter explains the Natziv's linguistic comment.

Comment: So you're saying that despite my IMO strong refutation of your reading of the _HD_, you'll stick by it because it answers my original question. Thanks for trying, but I'll await other readings….

Comment: @msh210 I'm not sure which strong refutation of my reading you mean. It all fits - Abraham asks "will we adopt a child?" and the Natziv explains his use of "תלד" in this context. It is hard to imagine any other reading of this.. But I would be happy to stand corrected.

Comment: The refutation I mean is that the _HD_ says "חלילה לא נסתפק א״א ביכולת הקב״ה" whereas you say that A. understood that God had said that A. would adopt, and A. doubted it. But there's more: According to your reading, A.'s doubt was would they adopt vs. would they not have a kid at all, whereas _HD_ sounds like it was would they adopt vs. would S. bear ("נסתפק בכונת הדבור וגם נתתי ממנה ולא אמר וגם תלד. ע״כ **אולי** אין הכונה שתלד ממש אלא אופן אחר", with emphasis supplied).

Comment: @msh210 But isn't there amazement here by Abraham any which way? Even if you explain this as you do, Abraham goes to the idea of adoption because of amazement at the more natural conclusion of child birth. So any which way there's amazement/disbelief here, the question is only about adoption vs birth.

Comment: Right, but the way I read it, A. doubts God meant birth (and expresses that doubt) and therefore concludes that God means adoption. So A. doesn't doubt God's abilities, just doubts that God could've meant birth. The way you read it, A. thinks God means adoption and A. expresses doubt as to adoption, which I think "חלילה לא נסתפק א״א ביכולת הקב״ה" precludes.

Comment: @msh210 I don't see why "A. doubts birth" as you said is legitimate, even if he concludes something else. He's saying "nah, can't be birth, must be adoption", which in my opinion falls the same way under "חלילה לא נסתפק". The Natziv's linguistic comment must relate to Abraham's words (since as you mentioned, Hashem didn't use the word "birth").

Comment: I don't think A. was doubting birth is possible. I think A. was doubting God meant birth. So indeed לא נסתפק א״א ביכולת הקב״ה.

Comment: @msh210 I see. You have me nearly convinced.. Then the only way to explain the Natziv's comment is that he wasn't emphasizing ״יולד״, he was saying generally that Abraham thought it might mean adoption, and that this still fits with Hashem's promise to give him a son from Sarah (i.e. an adopted child will still be considered Sarah's son, like with Naomi).